# What do the greyed out constraints in the visual debugger mean?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

What does a constraint being greyed out mean?  Are those inactive constraints?  Or constraints that are applying to the view but not actually a constraint in its `constraints` array?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The non-greyed constraints in the list of Auto Layout constraints in the size inspector in the Debug View Hierarchy are the ones that are active — being actually used by the runtime.

The greyed out constraints are the inactive ones, superseded by user explicit constraints, having a lower priority — being ignored by the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the **inactive** constraints. Mostly it happens when you apply constraints on another size class, that size class constraints become inactive if they are not applicable for current size classes.

Comment: looking at this some more, i'm not sure thats right.  it seems that the greyed out constraints always exist as un-grey-out constraints in the immediate subview.  is it possible that these grey constraints are constraints that affect the view but aren't in its constraints property?

Comment: i'm interested in the answer to this question.  apple doesn't explain this anywhere (at least anywhere obvious) and its important for debugging constraint issues!  and all the answers online are dubious or incomplete.

Comment: Only the non-greyed out constraints are affecting the layout. The greyed out may be active or inactive, but their priority is lower such that they don't actually effect the layout.

Comment: The built-in XCode documentation says that grayed-out constraints in the visual inspector (view debugger) are "implicit". No other explanation is given. Thanks again, Apple.